# Getting longitude,latitude without setting it all app life

Tags: iphone, objective-c, location

I want simple get lan,lon valus at the time application start,I dont want to update every second those values as I am changing my possition. I am using this code:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
  {
    latValueNSString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    lanValueNSString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

  }
```

But the problem that I cant transfer those values because every millisecond its setting it again and again... how can i set those values only ones and that's it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];` once you get a result. You may want to check if the accuracy is what you need before calling stop.

Comment: How can i know that i got them? I cant use `while` loop because if there's a problem it will never end...

Comment: Try `self.lastKnownLocation = nil;
        [self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:2000];
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` And then `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"updating position to %@", newLocation);
    self.lastKnownLocation = newLocation;
    
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 3000) {
        NSLog(@"Stop updating location.");
        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
`

Answer (score 2):

If you only need 1 value, just get the first location and tell the location manager to stop updating the location.

```
[manager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

do this when the delegate method is called.

Comment: How can i know that i got this values? i tried : `locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; [manager stopUpdatingLocation];` but saw that he never get in into the delegate. tried stopping it inside the delegate but its doesn't helped

Comment: You have to call stopUpdatingLocation after receiving a location on the delegate.

Comment: That is what i did, but it's continue coming into the delegate